# Best practice to store a lot of IDs into the database to search it in the future

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to save a lot of IDs into the database and search with php (via cronjob) if that ID is stored here or not...If is not stored, I need to process it and save into the database to avoid that the script processes it again

The IDs can be a lot, for example: last year 37,000, this year we expect about 60,000

I think the best practice is to store it via single value, but how about a serialized array? I can process 20-30 ids at time, and saving it into a single line, will it be worth?

Thanks

Comment: Storing anything other than individual values would seriously hinder the ability for searching. How often do you insert values and how often do you search them?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Storing 60k values in a database is not that hard, especially if that happens over a whole year

Comment: 60 000 id's? No problem, even if you host the dbms on a cell phone.

Comment: Insert values: 1-2 times a day, search: every minute about 100 ids at time until the status of the id change to "completed" (it will change at about 11AM every day)...
These values can change eveytime, maybe sometimes is 100, sometimes 50, and sometimes 200

Comment: Then just go the most conventional way - single values in a column with an index.

Comment: Yes I know that 60.000 ids is not a problem, but I'm just asking if storing and searching serialized data can be worth it

Comment: even 100.000 is anything but "a lot" in database terms. Just store in the separate rows

Comment: Nope, it doesn't worth. There are simpler ways to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to store the ids in a table -- and presumably with other information, such as the date/time the id was inserted.  And perhaps other information, such as who inserted it, how many times inserts were attempted afterwards, and so on.

Even 100,000 ids *per day* should not be a lot for a database to handle nowadays -- that is just a little bit more than 1 per second.  So, your volume is not big.

But, searching through tens or hundreds of thousands of rows can take some time.  To solve this, you want an index on `id`.  Or perhaps even to declare it as a primary key.  With an index, I would be surprised if the query time for a single `id` took more than a few milliseconds in almost any environment.

Comment: Yes, thank you I know...I will surely index the ID that I'll save into the DB, because I can use it to made some join with the main DB. BTW I need to store only id and date/time

Comment: @Helixior in MySQL you can autogenerate the `DATETIME` (or `TIMESTAMP`, etc.) column value when you insert the data so that's all taken care of for you `:-)`